# SQLAlchemy select clause as column

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I know the following can be achieved in a different way, but I am looking for a specific way of using select statements as a column in SQLAlchemy.

An example query is:

```
SELECT employee.*, (
        SELECT avg(salary) 
        FROM employee as e1 
        WHERE e1.department_id = e2.department_id
    ) as avg_salary
FROM employee as e2
```

I'm using only the Core component in SQLAlchemy. This is what I got so far:

```
e1 = employee.alias('e1')
e2 = employee.alias('e2')

inner = select(
  columns=[func.mean(e1.salary).label('avg_salary')],
  from_obj=e1
  whereclause=e1.department_id == e2.department_id
)

outer = select(
  columns=[e2, inner.avg_salary],
  from_obj=e2
)
```

However, this (`outer`) produces a `SELECT ... from employee as e1, (select ...) as e2` and not the desired query I am looking for.

How can I arrive at the SQL query using SQLAlchemy core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The select query has to be added to the columns with [`as_scalar`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/selectable.html?highlight=as_scalar#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.as_scalar). If I don't do this explicitly, SQLAlchemy renders the select query in the FROM section.

This is somewhat contradictory to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764358/how-to-use-subqueries-in-sqlalchemy-to-produce-a-moving-average) post which claims that `as_scalar` isn't necessary. But perhaps it's due to my query being different and a heuristic being used internally that figures out whether or not to put the query in the COLUMN or FROM section of the query.

Comment: Only question remaining is how I can label the column. Currently, it's returned as `anon_1`.

Comment: The documentation isn't very clear on this, so I answer here: It turns out that `select([column]).as_scalar.label('column_name')` is the way to go. I used `select.alias('column_name')` as this is how you'd normally name a select query (`SELECT ... AS colum_name`)

Comment: Instead of `select().as_scalar().label()` you can use `select().label()` directly as well.

Comment: ...Which is why the post you linked to works: it does exactly that.

Comment: I can confirm that `select().label()` works fine. Thanks for pointing me to my earlier question/answer, @IljaEverilä.